# Firestore Snapshot - Do we need to check if a returned doc .exists?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Imagine this situation:

```
const refs = [...];
const docs = await firestore.getAll(...refs);
```

Is it possible that a returned doc from the getAll() doesn't exist?

I mean, for me it hasn't got sense to get a doc that doesn't exist as result...

Is there any special situation where a returned doc does not exist?

```
docs.forEach((doc) => console.log(doc.exists));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The `data()` will return undefined if the document does not exist. Though you can filter the array and remove any non-existing documents as shown below:

```
const refs = [...];
const docsSnaps = await firestore.getAll(...refs);

const docs = docSnaps.filter(d => d.exists).map(d => d.data())
```

It's the [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) in which all documents returned exists since they match the query.